# how to format radians units in x axis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, x-axis, radians

I have a data file of 77*1 which is changing based on radians. I plotted my data and its ok in terms of figure itself. however, the x axis turned to be some random numbers. How can I define the thick labels in x axis to be in radians instead of random numbers. please see the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USWsD.png) .

```
figure
plot(Gamma_dif1, "r","LineWidth",2)
grid on;
ax=gca;
ax. Color='w';
y-axis left
ax.YColor='r';
ylabel('Gamma_difference','Color','r')
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an array: `rad = [0:theta/77:theta]`, where theta is the maximal angle you are plotting. Then, plot it as: `plot(rad, Gamma_dif1, "r","LineWidth",2)`.